# Uniform continuity on bounded open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $ f$ is uniformly continuous on a bounded open interval $ (a,b) $, then $ \lim_{x \to a^+}  f(x) $ and $ \lim_{x \to b^-}  f(x) $ exist and are finite.

I was reading this book: http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/T-CalculusIntegral-AllChapters-Portrait.pdf

the above is one direction of theorem 1.12, and is proven in exercise 65. I was having some trouble understanding the proof, and was hoping that someone might be able to explain it more in-depth.

Comment: What parts you don't understand? Try to be specific.

Comment: I suppose that I don't quite understand the point of the oscillation of a function, and its use in the proof.

Comment: Can you at least see, intuitively, why the oscillation is zero if and only if the function is continuous there, say?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Extension of uniformly continuous functions is discussed in detail in $\S$ 10.11 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf).

Comment: (I guess this is the way to go, the other notes are strange.)

Comment: @Peter: For some reason this basic result is hard to find in most elementary analysis courses.  I remember thinking that when I taught undergrad analysis at McGill almost ten years ago and making a point of putting it in the notes.  IIRC though, the course text used at the time (by Russell Gordon; it is really quite a good book) did treat this material, and I took my discussion more or less from there.